# Manage package is not visible in partners.salesforce.com > publishing > Component Listings > Component > Select Package

Tags: partner-communities

I have build and uploaded `unmanaged` and `managed` package, now when

1. I login to https://partners.salesforce.com
2. click publishing > Component Listings > Component > Select Package

I am able to see my `unmanaged` package but there is no `managed` appearing.

Here are the screen shots of `unmanaged` package.
[image]
[image]

I have uploaded package from `developer edition account`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it was not showing was while uploading package `beta managed package was selected`. Selecting `managed release` I was able to see it. Now the question is
[How do you convert your beta managed package to final(release) managed package](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161916/how-do-you-convert-your-beta-managed-package-to-finalrelease-managed-package)