# How do you convert your beta managed package to final(release) managed package

Tags: managed-package, beta-managed-package

How do you convert your `beta managed package` to `final(release) managed package`.
I have uploaded my package from `org1` and I have tested on `org2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you need to publish final managed package you need to check checkbox 
"Managed - Released" while uploading the package. 
[image]

Comment: This is helpful too [Upgrading Your App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_upgrading.htm)

Comment: superb dubey :)